# Anaconda install error - conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command

Tags: anaconda

I installed anaconda and I am having the issue as described below. I tried to reinstall but it is not working.

conda update --all also doesn't work

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda-script.py' (choose from 'info', 'help', 'list', 'search', 'create', 'install', 'update', 'upgrade', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'config', 'clean', 'package')
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type: conda -V

you can tell whether conda is installed or not. If it is installed try typing: conda update conda.  if that works try running Pyton and see what you get.  If the above commands fail, i would restart your computer and run the Anaconda uninstaller. You should have access to this from the Anacondapage.  Now try to reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: jmh thanks for the answer!

Running conda -V
I got  conda 4.3.16


, and Running conda update conda
I got PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Anaconda3
  package name: conda

Comment: If I run conda install conda then stuck in ```setuptools-36. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   3.65 MB/s ```and then give the follow error message ```Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\D************\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\conda\gateways\disk\read.py", line 44, in yield_lines
        with open(path) as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\conda-env-2.6.0-0\\info\\has_prefix'
```